# Windows Batch wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory

Tags: windows, batch-file, wmic

i try to write a batch file which gives me the free physical memory. This batch should write every X seconds a timestamp and the following command in a text file:

```
wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory
```

My batch file looks like this:

```
:loop
(
@echo %time% %date%  
wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value
)>testMEMORY.txt
timeout /t 10 
goto loop
```

This is the output:

```
13:54:54,76 04.11.2019  




 F r e e P h y s i c a l M e m o r y = 7 2 0 6 6 4 8
```

I don't get it, why i have a lot of new lines and after each character a space. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of WMIC is unicode !

The trailing `<CR>` can be removed by passing the value through another `FOR /F` loop.

This also removes the phantom "blank" line (actually a `<CR>`)

```bat
@echo off
If Exist testMEMORY.txt Del testMEMORY.txt
:loop
(
    @echo %time% %date%  
    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value') do (
        for /f "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
            echo %%b
        )
    )
)>>testMEMORY.txt
timeout /t 10 /nobreak>nul 
goto loop
```

So, i got as result in `testMEMORY.txt` something like that :

> ```
> 15:32:19.02 04/11/2019  
> FreePhysicalMemory=528592
> 15:32:29.19 04/11/2019  
> FreePhysicalMemory=530804
> 15:32:39.14 04/11/2019  
> FreePhysicalMemory=531156
> 15:32:49.21 04/11/2019  
> FreePhysicalMemory=530968
> 15:32:59.16 04/11/2019  
> FreePhysicalMemory=531936
> 15:33:09.23 04/11/2019  
> FreePhysicalMemory=530376
> 15:33:19.18 04/11/2019  
> FreePhysicalMemory=524980
> 15:33:29.16 04/11/2019  
> FreePhysicalMemory=521816
> 15:33:39.21 04/11/2019  
> FreePhysicalMemory=465820
> 15:33:49.17 04/11/2019  
> FreePhysicalMemory=461312
> 15:33:59.17 04/11/2019  
> FreePhysicalMemory=385172
> 15:34:14.21 04/11/2019  
> FreePhysicalMemory=529800
> 15:34:24.13 04/11/2019  
> FreePhysicalMemory=541064
> ```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

As there's little to no chance that your command output will contain characters unavailable outside of UTF-16, I would offer this simple fix which in my opinion would provide acceptable output.

```bat
:Loop
@>"testMEMORY.txt" (    Echo %TIME% %DATE%
    WMIC OS Get FreePhysicalMemory /Value|Find "=")
@Timeout 10 >NUL 
@GoTo Loop
```

Comment: Works great too! Thanks for the help!